# Arithmetic Right Shift without using shift operators

Tags: verilog, bit-shift

I want to write a `16 Bit Arithmetic right shift function` in `verilog` without using `shift operators`.

**My Code so far:**

```
module my_shift(Number, Range, Shifted);
  input [15:0] Number;
  input [3:0] Range;
  output[15:0] Shifted;
  reg Shifted;

always @(Number)
  Shifted = shifted_number(Number, Range);
   
    function[15:0] shifted_number;
     input [15:0] number;
     input [3:0] Range;         //4 bit shift range
     integer i;
     integer j;
     
     begin
         for (i = 0; i < Range; i = i + 1) begin
             for (j = 0; j < 15; j = j + 1) begin
                shifted_number[j] = number[j+1];
             end
         end
         shifted_number[15] = number[15];
     end
      
    endfunction

endmodule
```

I wrote a simple Testbench to test my `function`.
I just want to `shift` three different numbers by 1 `bit`.

**My Testbench:**

```
module test;
reg [15:0] Number;
reg [3:0] Range;
wire[15:0]  shifted;

my_shift shift_number(Number, Range,shifted);

initial
$monitor($time," -->Number = %b, shifted = %b, ",Number,shifted);

initial begin
Range = 1;
Number = 3; 

#10;
Number = 4; 

#10;
Number = 5; 

#100 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Which gives me the following `output`:

> 0 -->Number = 0000000000000011, shifted = 0000000000000001,
>
> 10 -->Number = 0000000000000100, shifted = 0000000000000000,
>
> 20 -->Number = 0000000000000101, shifted = 0000000000000000,

It compiles but there is a warning at:

`my_shift shift_number(Number, Range,shifted);`

**The warning:**

`warning: Port sizes don't match in port #3`

Why does the compiler give me this warning and why is the output incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You incorrectly declared `Shifted` as a 1-bit `reg`:

Change:

```
  output [15:0] Shifted;
  reg Shifted;
```

to:

```
  output reg [15:0] Shifted;
```

I now get this output:

```
           0 -->Number = 0000000000000011, shifted = 1000000000000001, 
          10 -->Number = 0000000000000100, shifted = 1000000000000010, 
          20 -->Number = 0000000000000101, shifted = 1000000000000010,
```

I ran your code on 2 different simulators and got much more helpful warning and error messages.  You can try your luck on **edaplayground**.

Comment: You were right. Although in `Veriwell` you have to use 
`output [15:0] Shifted;
  reg [15:0] Shifted;`